# Using a batch file to sort and delete files based on time

Tags: datetime, batch-file, timer

for my research we take 100's of pictures a day of the sky. As of now we have 20,000 plus pictures in this folder, but we only need pictures taken at night. Is there a way to automatically remove pictures between set times, say like 9 am to 5 pm using a batch file? I have no DOS experience, but for this kind of task it seems the most efficient way instead of MATLAB (which I am more familiar with). Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What format are the filenames in?  The files can be filtered by last modified date etc, or by filename format.  Filename format is preferable if it is already in a useful format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%a in ('dir /o-d /b') do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%b in ("%%~ta") do (
    set "ftime=%%c" & set "ftime=!ftime: =0!"
      if !ftime! GEQ 09:00 if !ftime! LEQ 17:00 (
         echo Timestamp: %%~ta Ok to delete %%~nxa
         echo del %%~nxa
      )
   )
)
```

Once you run through it and verify the correct files are identified, remove the echo on the del %%~nxa line to do the actual delete.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Hey Matt, I ran the code but it seems like nothing is happening. I removed the echo for a test run for 10 pictures with dates between 9am and 5pm and none of them got deleted. To be clear I just copied that text into a text file and saved it with a .bat extension, then added that file into the folder with the pictures and then ran it. Thanks again for your help. For clarification, all the pictures are .jpg

Comment: Is your date format month/day/year? I'm in the U.S. and I sometimes forget that many posters aren't. You might have to switch `"%MM%/%DD%/%YYYY%"` to `"%DD%/%MM%/%YYYY%"`

Comment: No I am in the United States so that is correct. I'll try it again on the research computer and not my personal one. On the previous attempts the first echo line wouldn't show up either if that helps.

Comment: That's because I had a filter for the current day. If none of the files were taken today, it wouldn't have worked. I've removed the filter so it will delete ANY files created between 9AM and 5PM on any day. See if that works for you.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much it works now, appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. could you please click the checkmark for this answer so future visitors will know right away that it worked